# Loop autohotkey script moving mouse down each time

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to automate my workflow using Autohotkey.

I want to move the mouse position down 200px each iteration at the two positions marked below; and apologies for the formatting.

EDIT: Thanks to the answer below I have learnt to think of other ways to make a repeating action. I ended up using TinyTask to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable for the X coordinate and then use += 200 to add to the variables value. But it maybe simpler to use the keyboard to do it something like

```
send, {down 3}{F2}
```

Also autohotkey 1.1+ from http://ahkscript.org has COM built-in so that excel can be fully controled almost like vba

Comment: Using the keyboard does make far more sense.

As I would just have to loop it; however despite reading my revised script it simply stops when any mouse action occurs.

I have even tried the mousekeys utility in windows to control via keyboard that doesn't work either. Revised above.

Ty for your help

Comment: As I can't test your setup its hard to say, you can try and right click the tray icon (its the green one with the H) and select open, this will show you the last line the script has executed... this can help you debug what's going on when the script stops